# Mass is affecting final velocity down ramp

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, friction, velocity

I have been doing an experiment where 2 different skateboard frames (like a grind) slide down a metal ramp (1.5m) and the final velocity is calculated by video analysis. I would compare this to the theoretical velocity (which is calculated by finding coefficient of friction (at what angle the board starts sliding)). In my results, I was surprised when skateboard 1 had an increasing velocity when more weight was added. I recalculated the coefficient of friction after all the tests. It showed that the coefficient of friction was lower by 2.25 degrees on skateboard 1, but not on skateboard 2. I recalculated the final velocity theoretically for skateboard 1 and it was still far under the experimental velocity (velocity with no weights was 2.2m/s and with max weights was 3.12. final velocity for Max weights experimentally calculated to be 2.7).

I think this may have something to do with the paint on skateboard 1's board since the skateboard 2's board did not have an increasing velocity with mass

I am wondering if there is some explanation for this. I measured the coefficient throughout the ramp and it is fairly consistent start to finish. Could the paint on the skateboard perhaps create a reaction that lowers the coefficient even further (this could make sense since more force is applied with more weight). If anyone knows any literature that may help, that would be awesome.

The results for skateboard 1 and 2 respectively;

- 2.5kg       2.4m/s.        2.25m/s
- 7.5kg       2.55m/s.      2.47m/s
- 12.5kg.    2.88m/s.      2.4m/s
- 17.5kg.    3.12m/s.      2.46m/s

Coefficient before / after

- skateboard 1: 17° to 14.2°
- skateboard 2: 17° to 16.2°

5 trials per weight per board. Trials had a max error of  +-0.12m/s. Boards were dropped at a 30° angle. The angle was secured and if anything, decreased over time, not increased

Comment: To calculate the velocity did you split its weight  into its components and considered the force component along the ramp , subtracted  the frictional force,- get the net force. Divide by mass - get the acceleration. Double it - your final velocity. Is this the approach you used?

Comment: Yes that is what I did, except I used a the formula v^2 = u^2 + 2as.  I've confirmed that all my theoretical calculations are correct. It accounts for friction but not air resistance